# how to apply fade out effect on image using grails?

Tags: java, grails, grails-plugin

I want to apply effects like fade in , fade out on images, and convert it into video.
Is there any grails plugin to apply such effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Grails doesn't have any plugins to convert images to videos.

Comment: Ohk.and what about effects on images? I tried to use https://grails.org/plugin/imagezoom. is there any other way to do such thing?

Comment: There are quite a few image manipulation plugins: https://grails.org/plugins/search?q=image

Comment: Effects on images are done on client side. Why are you looking for it in Grails rather than in jQuery for example?

Comment: @lukelazarovic if said images are being used on a web page, then you are right. However he didn't specify if that was the case. I have several projects that need to manipulate images server-side and this may be their case too. Good point though about client-side plugins.

Comment: Actually I found api (http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/) for creating video from images. my app is in grails 2.3.7, but now i want to send image list with effects like fade in or out so when I generate video those images come with effects.

Comment: @JoshueMoore You are right of course, there is not enough information in the question to distinguish these cases